# Field not updating in MongoDB using FastAPI

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, fastapi

I have a document schema that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "8a28d1fc-602b-43ba-a017-105a4fff35b3",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "user": {
    "timestamp": "2023-03-03",
    "phone": "+012345678912",
    "age": 25,
    "gender": "male",
    "nationality": "smth",
    "universityMajor": "ENGINEERING",
    "preferences": {
      "doesMindHavingPets": true
    },
    "password": "$2b$12$9dRbQF2N5kAM44JBAphrrOWT23d206TIZ.VWMhZ9m.PwqnHEZKNhO"
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement an update function using FastAPI, the function looks like this:

```
async def updateUser (id: str, user: BasicUserUpdate = Body(...)):
    new_user = user.dict(exclude_none=True)
    user_preferences = None

    if "preferences" in new_user:
        user_preferences = new_user['preferences']
        del new_user ['preferences']

    if 'password' in new_user:
        new_user['password'] = get_hashed_password(new_user['password'])
        
    print (new_user['password'])
    if (len(new_user) + len(user_preferences)) >= 1:  # type: ignore
        update_result = await dbConnection.find_one_and_update(
        {"_id": id, "isDeleted" : False}, 
        [
            { "$set": 
                { "user.preferences": 
                    { "$mergeObjects": 
                        [ "$user.preferences", user_preferences ] 
                    } 
                }
            },
            { "$set": 
                { "user": 
                    { "$mergeObjects": 
                        [ "$user", new_user ] 
                    } 
                }
            }           
        ], 
        return_document = ReturnDocument.AFTER)

        if update_result is not None:
            return update_result['user']
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"User {id} not found, or has been banned")
```

The function *get_hashed_password* is below:

```
password_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")


def get_hashed_password(password: str) -> str:
    return password_context.hash(password)
```

All the updating for all the fields works fine except for the password. As you can see, there is a print, `print (new_user['password'])`, statement right before I update it in MongoDB. That print statement displays the correct new hashed password. However, when MongoDB executes the update statement, everything updates properly except for the password.

Below is an example of a sample body sent to the function:

```
{
    "highPrivacy" : "true",
    "password" : "abcd1234",
    "preferences" : {
        "doesMindHavingPets" : "true",
        "isMorningPerson" : "false"
    }
}
```

When I send this body to the function, a `print(new_user)` statement will print the following:

```
{'password': '$2b$12$7256L8YrH1Yz5/S0GutFM.og1fckAoWUboVqZepMLXZ9KnHk4PwrC', 'highPrivacy': True}
```

As you can see, the hash is different here, but this never updates in MongoDB, and the password will always remain as *$2b$12$9dRbQF2N5kAM44JBAphrrOWT23d206TIZ.VWMhZ9m.PwqnHEZKNhO*

What is the issue here, the behavior is very weird especially because all the other fields update normally, so there does not seem to be any issue with the MongoDB query logic itself.

Comment: Are you use another password in every test ?

Comment: @milad_vayani I tried with different passwords, but that shouldn't matter, because the hash should be different every time, even if the same password is used.
For example, the word "abcd" could be hashed to _$2b$ssdguas_ one time, but if you hash "abcd" again you might get something different like _$2b$uywqgshd_

Comment: No,I think that's your problem.
The hash result for abcd always has the same output.

Comment: It doesn't, as you can see in the print statement, the hash printed out is different from the one in the document. So they hash function returns different hashes